# Character Pawn sliding back when picking up objects

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am using Unreal Engine to create a puzzle game. In this game, the player has to pick up a chair/table and place it on a pressure plate in another part of the room in order to unlock a door.

When play testing, picking up objects causes my character to slide back. Once the sliding starts, there is no way to make the character stop sliding. I suspect that this issue may be caused by the object's collision volume entering the character's. However, when I release the object, my character keeps gliding backwards even though by then, the object's collision volume is out of reach.

On my character's blueprint I have locked rotation on all axes, so that it won't randomly start rolling backwards after picking up an object. This solves part of the issue but there is still the gliding that just won't stop.

I am new to UE and I have no idea what may be causing this issue. If you have any previous experience in this or simply want to chime in, please do!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative fix is to lock the rotation of the collision component in the default pawn that you have or to increase angular damping.

To do so, open the default pawn blueprint and under the physics section, then constraints, lock rotation in the X, Y, and Z axis. Or increase angular damping.

Comment: The original poster and myself are following the same tutorial, and both methods you proposed corrected the sliding issue for me, although I'm not familiar enough to understand why locking the rotation of the player solves it. 

Another aspect was to increase the grab distance that an object is held at so that it doesn't collide into the player's volume.

Comment: I understand now. Ejecting from the player, you can observe that picking up the object too closely pushed the player over like a falling domino. That explains the sliding that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why this is happening exactly unless we see the actual settings you are using and the BP but when you pick up the object , disable its physics and collision and when you put it back enable it after a delay of 0.5 or 1 second . Hope this helps.